# Matlab: vectorize assignment of values in matrix based on index

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

Apologies in advance if this question is a duplicate, or if the solution to this question is very straightforward in Matlab. I have a M x N matrix `A`, a 1 x M vector `ind`, and another vector `val`. For example,

```
A = zeros(6,5);
ind = [3 4 2 4 2 3];
val = [1 2 3];
```

I would like to vectorize the following code:

```
for i = 1 : size(A,1)
    A(i, ind(i)-1 : ind(i)+1) = val;
end

>> A

A =

 0     1     2     3     0
 0     0     1     2     3
 1     2     3     0     0
 0     0     1     2     3
 1     2     3     0     0
 0     1     2     3     0
```

That is, for row i of `A`, I want to insert the vector `val` in a certain location, as specificied by the i'th entry of `ind`. What's the best way to do this in Matlab without a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done using **[`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability**: build a mask telling where the values will be placed, and then fill those values in. In doing this, it's easier to work with columns instead of rows (because of Matlab's column major order), and transpose at the end.

The code below determines the **minimum number of columns** in the final `A` so that all values fit at the specified positions.

Your example applies a displacement of `-1` with respect to `ind`. The code includes a **generic displacement**, which can be modified.

```
%// Data
ind = [3 4 2 4 2 3]; %// indices
val = [1 2 3]; %// values
d = -1; %// displacement for indices. -1 in your example

%// Let's go
n = numel(val);
m = numel(ind);
N = max(ind-1) + n + d;  %// number of rows in A (rows before transposition)
mask = bsxfun(@ge, (1:N).', ind+d) & bsxfun(@le, (1:N).', ind+n-1+d); %// build mask
A = zeros(size(mask)); %/// define A with zeros
A(mask) = repmat(val(:), m, 1); %// fill in values as indicated by mask
A = A.'; %// transpose
```

Result in your example:

```
A =
     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     1     2     3
     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3
     1     2     3     0     0
     0     1     2     3     0
```

Result with `d = 0` (no displacement):

```
A =
     0     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3
     0     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3     0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can handle a bit of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) *overdose*, here's one with `bsxfun's` *adding capability* -

```
N = numel(ind);
A(bsxfun(@plus,N*[-1:1]',(ind-1)*N + [1:N])) = repmat(val(:),1,N)
```

Sample run -

```
>> ind
ind =
     3     4     2     4     2     3
>> val
val =
     1     2     3
>> A = zeros(6,5);
>> N = numel(ind);
>> A(bsxfun(@plus,N*[-1:1]',(ind-1)*N + [1:N])) = repmat(val(:),1,N)
A =
     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     1     2     3
     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3
     1     2     3     0     0
     0     1     2     3     0
```

Comment: Haha! I stole your answer! :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I was afraid I stole from yours! Completely off-topic it got me thinking few days ago, I never thought `bsxfun` would feature in a meta post, but you made that happen with that latest post on 10-M Questions thingy, so thank you for that too! :) BTW I love that term `masking capability`, makes it sound like bsxfun has a superpower, which in a way is TRUE! ;)

Comment: It's your term, you coined it! And yes, `bsxfun` deserved a meta post, and so you did! :-D